# matplotlib animation with multiple plots and for loop

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

hey I'm trying to get matplotlib.animation to plot n plots in one graph like the first code block below, but when I run the script everything seems to run except none of the plots show up.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data to be ploted
x = []
y = []
x2 = []
y2 = []
for i in range(-9,9):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(i**2)
    x2.append(i)
    y2.append(i**3)
# plot the data
plt.plot(x,y, label = 'first line')
# plot other data points
plt.plot(x2,y2, label = 'second line')
# add this before plt.show() to add labels to graph
plt.xlabel('X value')
plt.ylabel('Y value')
# add a title to graph
plt.title('interesting graph\nsubtitle')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

here is the code using animate:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

# better face
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def anima(i):
    graph_data = open('a.txt').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    dataPoints = []
    for i in lines:
        # ignor empty lines

        if len(i) > 1:
            line = i.split('|') # delimiter is |

            for a in range(len(line)):
                try:
                    dataPoints[a].append(int(line[a]))
                # if there is no dataPoint[a] it gets created
                except:
                    dataPoints.append(int(line[a]))
    # modify axis
    ax1.clear()
    # plot
    for i in range(len(dataPoints)-1):
        ax1.plot(dataPoints[1],dataPoints[i+1])

#where to animate, what to animate, how often to update
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, anima, interval = 1000)
plt.show()
```

in a.txt I have this:

```
1|56|80|62
2|123|135|55
12|41|12|23
60|12|45|23
12|43|56|54
25|123|23|31
2|213|31|84
61|1|68|54
62|2|87|31
63|4|31|53
64|8|13|13
65|16|51|65
66|32|43|84
80|62|42|15
```

update:
I gave up on reading a file and am having a threaded function generate values for me and instead for having everything in one plot I am having everything in subplots(the number is going to be edited soon). when I run the code with a normal plot it works fine, but when I try to use animate... it shows the graphs but no plot once again. my problem is showing the animated plot

```js
# check if os is linux
import platform
if str(platform.system()).lower() == str('linux').lower():
    # must be set befor importing any other matplotlib
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from threading import Thread

# Change style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure()
#list with all datapoints eg: [timeList],[graph1List].... 
data_points = []
# 'name' of each graph in the list
graphs_ = [0]

def create_plots():
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for i in range(-10,11):
        x = i
        y = i**3

        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)
    data_points.append(xs)
    data_points.append(ys)

t = Thread(target=create_plots)
t.start()

def anima(i):
    for i in range(len(graphs_)):
        graphs_[i]=fig.add_subplot(211+i)
        graphs_[i].clear()
        graphs_[i].plot(0,i+1)

while len(data_points) == 0:
    print('.')


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, anima, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm lost on why there are two different codes. Which one is the one you're having problems with? if it's the second, what's the purpose of showing the first (and vice versa)?

Comment: You shouldn't have a generic `except` -- it should specify the error that is handled by that code, such as `ValueError` etc. Makes it hard to debug other weird errors. I'd do `for a in line:`and `int(a)` to step through the values directly instead of using a numeric index (or use a more descriptive name than `a`)...

Comment: I showed the first code just to show the result I wanted get using animate. thanks for the suggestions I'll add ValueError as for adding a more descriptive name now I'm just trying to get something basic to work when it starts working I'll edit it to be easier to read.

Comment: is what I want to do(in either case) possible?

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you sure your `anima(i)` function gets called?

2) Why are you overwriting the variable i in `anima(i)` and again in line?

```
    for i in lines:
        # ignor empty lines
```

Comment: yes I'm sure its being called. from the parts that i changed from the working script are: for a in range(len(line)) loop and for i in range(len(dataPoints)-1) loop